# what tools to use to automatize custom workflow on macos (copy, paste, do action)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, automation, automator

I want to automatize custom workflows on macOS. I wonder what tools should i use. The process is:

1. copy data from webpage
2. paste the data into another program field on macOS
3. application action

**What I think are the necessary steps:**

1. I need to parse HTML and get the data. I can do that in javascript (google sheets) or find a way.
   (Maybe should i use another tool - terminal / python / apple script / automator?)
2. save the data to macOS disk
3. push the data into program field
4. run the application with the data

**What i dont know:**

What tools to learn to perform these tasks (python / automator / applescript or other?).

**Similar case:**

Its similiar to what I have already seen with messages. People automaticly copy data from textfile and sends them in parts as a messages using python script.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you will need `requests` or `selenium` for downloading the content, and `BeautifulSoup` to parse the content, then you can the items you want in a file using

```
with open("somefile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

with python you can surely do that.  For parsing HTML you can explore Selenium and BeautifulSoup libraries.  Then for files, you can explore os library.  For other two tasks, it depends on the program I guess.